# How do I copy a project out of TFS

Tags: tfs

I want to copy a project out of TFS so I can "stuff around" with it locally without affecting any of the server files. How do I do this?

Please answer this simple question

Comment: what no one knows how to do this. help us all.

Comment: Patience, Bob.  You waited all of an hour for an answer before you entered your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your local copy never affects the server copy of the files until you "check in" your results.  Work with it as much as you want, locally, then, if you want to discard your changes, right click on the solution, and choose "Undo Changes."

Comment: You also have th option to create an additoinal workspace if you already have "code you want to keep" that is not checked in. In addition if you want to be able to check-in to protect you stuffing around then create a branch.